# How do I display the .cpp and .h files in the left side of the the codeblocks ide?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

When I create a new project it automatically shows me the .cpp files in under Workspace>Project>Source and .h files in headers. If I then save it and close Codeblocks and open the project again, it will only display the main.cpp and further add .cpp and .h files if I create more classes.
How can I make it display the .cpp and .h files neatly like when I work on a new project?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not getting it wrong. Your codeblocks saves the project with the extension `.cbp`.

- First, Open your project.
- Go-to `View`.
- Click `Open files list`. You will see a list of all files currently being shown on the right-side of the editor.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it wasn't it. I tried that before.
I found a solution today. Right click on the project name under Workspace and "add files"